# How can I delete a field from a DBF file when encoding is not supported?

Tags: python, dbf

I have multiple DBF files with fiels with latin characters in the name, e.g. "Año". I am trying to read the tables and export them to CSVs. Using python libraries, I´ve used the dbf library and it it has issues when try to export to CSV, or change or delete the field name.

I´ve tried all possible spanish encodings (codepage) to read the file.

Reading a DBF File (this part works)

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\test.dbf', codepage="cp1252")
print (table)
```

But when I try the following:

```
table.delete_fields('año')
```

I get this error even though the field appeared listed when I printed the file.

```
field año not in table -- delete aborted
```

The same thing happens when I try to export the DBF file to CSV:

```
dbf.export(table, "junk.csv")
```

Here´s the documentation for the library that I am using:
https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/dbf-module.html

I´ve tried using the dbfread library but whenever it hits an empty row it stops, so not useful for reading entire DBF tables.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you send me a copy of the table?  I'd like to fix that bug.

Comment: I could post a section of the table here, but is there another way where I can send you the file privately?

Comment: ethan dot stoneleaf at gmail dot com  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that specifying codepage at dbf.Table **init** doesn't set the right codepage.
A workaround is to change it manually by assigning:

```
with table:
    table.codepage=dbf.CodePage("cp1252")
```